# Is the content of this answer actually a bad thing?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

Please take a look at my answer here: [Bioshock has no sound in Windows 7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7831/bioshock-has-no-sound-in-windows-7/9357#9357)

I have played this game and shared the problem encountered by user "Mr. Shiny and New". I was able to solve the issue mentioned and put-in what worked for me. This answer was however down-voted with no comments.

When I inquired as to the reason for getting a down-vote I was informed that it was because I had mentioned using a "no-dvd crack".

I want to mention the following points:

1) I don't think a no-dvd crack is [illegal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-CD_crack) as per the usage mentioned.

2) Whether it contains malware or not depends largely on where you're downloading it from. Till now [I haven't encountered](http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/gamecopyworld.com) a single malware from gamecopyworld.com.

3) Until the time Xantec commented on my answer it stood at -1 for quite some time. I felt discouraged to answer anymore questions for this time.

**Question: Is the content of this answer actually a bad thing?**

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:** Thank you Grace for your suggestion on what we should be focusing on. I agree with you completely on this and have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: People are allowed to upvote and downvote at their discretion and to their understanding of a situation. Our guidelines for voting are given to you when you hover over the voting buttons. If you find it useful and/or clear, upvote. If you find it not useful and not clear, downvote. How one judges usefulness is up to the individual, not up to some community mandate.

Comment: I think that instead of thinking about "should we upvote or downvote", you should instead focus on the *actual* issue here. Say, "What is the issue in this answer?" or "Is the content of this answer actually a bad thing?". Ask about the content, not how it's rated, and that's how you'll actually see if it is appropriate.

Comment: A no-disc crack is *absolutely* illegal, regardless of the purpose for which it's used. While you may own the game, and while it may constitute fair-use for you to have additional copies of the data, etc., the way the law exists, as-written in the US, is that the act of circumvention of the DRM on the software is *in itself* illegal, regardless of whether you are engaging in that activity to accomplish a legal goal.

Comment: @Less Do you mind if I interrogate your further as to what defines a "crack"? I'm not arguing against your stance, but... for example, when Diablo II had one of its later patches, Blizzard added the ability to run it without needing the CD anymore (if you copied the BGM), and I've seen that referred to as a "no-CD crack". I'm inclined to believe that terminology isn't accurate, so could you help me understand this a bit better? (Feel free to drop it all on chat if it's long, I'll be reading it ♪)

Comment: @Less Please correct me if I'm wrong but I believe it *actually is* legal to use a no-cd crack in certain conditions. You are legally *allowed* to make a personal backup of an Original Game CD/DVD as long as you are the owner of the Original Game CD/DVD and provided you do *not* sell, rent or give away any backups of copyrighted Games CD/DVD's. *[†: swapped <i> tags for italic formatting]*

Comment: @mugen You're legally allowed to make a copy. You're not legally allowed to circumvent DRM in order to do so. I'm legally allowed to take a walk in the park. I'm not legally allowed to cut a hole in the fence to get in.

Comment: @Grace Yea, calling a change to a game by it's publisher a no-cd crack is terminology fail. The use of the term 'crack' specifically implies circumvention of some manner of DRM or other security system in place designed to prevent you from playing the game without the CD. Now, for some older games, there is no DRM, and the process of running without a CD amounts to 'drag and drop all the files to a folder on your hard drive. Point game at it.' That's perfectly fine. But the minute you're dealing with any sort of workaround or circumvention of DRM, you are absolutely doing something illegal.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there is a large amount of conflation in the tech community of 'what should be legal' with 'what is legal' which conveniently ignores the specifics of the law as written. Since 'Fair Use' allows for a variety of exceptions to one aspect of copyright law (your right to copy at all), many people misapply it where it does not apply (circumvention provision), in a misguided attempt to claim moral high ground.

Comment: It should be noted that there *is* a fair use exemption in place for circumvention of DRM attached to Video Games playable on PC's. However, this exemption is extremely narrowly defined -  such circumvention is only legal for the express purpose of security research and for the identification and repair of security vulnerabilities that may arise in connection with said DRM. It *does not* apply to the production of 'backup copies' or increased convenience/reduced load times/improved functionality via not using optical media.

Comment: For more information on the DMCA, as well as the specific exemptions currently in place, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act), [here](http://www.chillingeffects.org/anticircumvention/faq.cgi#QID117) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-circumvention).

Comment: @Less I'm going to find a way to drag your rant on the chat onto the Meta site. Somewhere, somehow. I'm not sure what it'll be like. But I think it'll be something nice to be able to point at come future. Also, thank you much for the explanation. ♪

Comment: @LessPop At this point, I"d just combine your comments into a single answer.

Comment: @Less Thanks for your detailed response with multiple links, Less.  :) This rule sounds like a catch 22. You can only do something by doing something else that you can't do. Less, what do you think about the disclaimer mentioned in gamecopyworld.com? (Just click on a mirror and you get the disclaimer).

Comment: It's absolutely a Catch-22, and GCW's disclaimer is utterly toothless. It doesn't matter how much you warn people that they are about to engage in illegal activity, they, and you, are still liable for the consequences of whatever illegal activity in which you engage.

Comment: @Less maybe with all your information you could make an answer.

Comment: @LessPop: If you can classify a CD as a dongle for the purposes of copyright protection, then this clause applies: "Computer programs protected by dongles that prevent access due to malfunction or damage and which are obsolete. A dongle shall be considered obsolete if it is no longer manufactured or if a replacement or repair is no longer reasonably available in the commercial marketplace. (A renewed exemption from 2006, based on a similar exemption approved in 2003.)"